# evaluateJavaScript used for an entire file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need an editor of mine to evaluate the JS code in whatever JS file I have open. However, it never does. Although the app output says

```
    QIODevice::read: device not open
```

Here's my code (mFilename is the variable that holds the open file's filename)

```
    QFile sFile(mFilename);
    QTextStream in(&sFile);
    text = in.readAll();
    sFile.close();

    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to open the file. To open it you have to use QFile::open method.
If you want to read it just call the file.open like that:

```
sFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

Indeed you didn't open the file by calling the QFile constructor.

So, your code would now be:

```
QFile sFile(mFilename);
QTextStream in(&sFile);
sFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
text = in.readAll();
sFile.close();

ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(text);
```

Comment: It is missing a Q, but other than that thank you! Just the answer I needed